# Avoiding var _this = this; when writing jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

Not a very important question, but here we go..

How do you avoid using var _this = this in jQuery event handlers?
i.e. I don't like doing:

```
var _this = this;
$(el).click(function (event) {
  //use _this to access the object and $(this) to access dom element
});
```

The following 2 ways are not ideal

```
$(el).click($.proxy(function (event) {
  //lost access to the correct dom element, i.e. event.target is not good enough (see http://jsfiddle.net/ne3n3/1/)
}, this));

$(el).click({_this: this}, function (event) {
  //have access to $(this) and event.data._this, but it seems too verbose
})
```

Ideally I would like to do something like

```
$(el).click(function (event) {
  this.method(); // this is accessing the object
  event.realTarget; // this is accessing the dom element
}, this); // <= notice this
```

Comment: Please explain why do you thing "event.target is not good enough"? jQuery always returns own well-formed event object, with correct event.target value.

Comment: I avoid it by not typing it in the first place....

Comment: When I say "not good enough" I mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/ne3n3/ There is a difference between event.target and this that jQuery prepares for me in the handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/ says:

> "This property will typically be equal to the this of the function."

http://jsfiddle.net/ne3n3/2/

Comment: Do you know if this event property is set by jQuery or is that a DOM thing?

Comment: It's in jQuery since version added: 1.3, so must be a jQuery feature.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure I understand you right, but if what you want is a reference to the function you were in when creating the callback function you *could* do it like this (although it's not exactly saving you any typing):

```
$(el).click(function(parent) {
    return function() {
        // Use parent instead of _this
    }
}(this))
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I guess it's not so much about saving typing, but rather improving readability.

Comment: @Karolis If you want to improve readability, don't call it `_this`, but rather something contextually/semantically meaningful. Either do it this way (but choose a meaningful name), or the original way--that's about as readable as you're going to get, IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. It's just somewhat annoying that in most of my callbacks I proxy/dojo.hitch 'this' (if it's needed) and the jQuery event handlers are the only exception where they treat 'this' in a special way. Perhaps, jQuery could pass a reference to the dom element as an argument instead of touching 'this'. I.e. .bind( eventType, [eventData,] handler(eventObject, domElement) )

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the variable `this` to both the object and the DOM element.  My recommendation is to assign the object to a different variable than `this`.

The best way to access both the object and the DOM element would be something like the following:

```
$(el).click($.proxy(function (event) {
  // can reference DOM element with this i.e. $(this)
  // can reference your object with the variable myObject
  //     i.e. $(this).val(myObject.data);
}, myObject));
```

or maybe like this:

```
$(el).click({myObject: this}, function (event) {
  //have access to $(this) and event.data.myObject, but it seems too verbose
});
```

Using a variable other than `this` inside the click event handling function will also make your code clearer, since most people would expect `this` to reference the DOM element and have nothing to do with your custom object.

Comment: Your first example doesn't work, because I don't have a reference to myObject. I could do var myObject = this; but that's the same as var _this = this;

Comment: Your second example is a bit annoying, cause event.data.myObject feels like too much typing when you could do that with this keyword. If that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, you're right about the first example.  I forgot that $.proxy() re-assigned the passed in object reference to this.  My bad.